# intel ipp function equivalent to for loop

Tags: image-processing, intel-ipp

I am new on image processing, I'm trying something to do on Intel IPP.
I need a ipp function which scan the matrix sequentially as FOR LOOP, but faster than FOR.

thank you.

Comment: IPP doesn't work that way, what do you want to do in your loop?

Comment: Not loop but, I have a different question, I have to do labeling every pixel on 2 dimensional picture frame. With Ipp